# Use Ajax Call to load a view in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a page in my view folder what I want to do is that whenever a navigation menu link is clicked, it loads it without refreshing the browser inside a div tag of my index page.

Comment: Views are loaded by controllers.  Controllers are what's loaded when you visit a URL.

Comment: Also, what's your question?

Comment: also where's the code ?

Comment: It appears you don't understand my question

Comment: @FavourChukwuedo: You don't exactly have a *question*.

Comment: @FavourChukwuedo: What have you tried?  What part of this are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_page_content(page) {
    $.get("pages/" + page, function(data) {
        $("#container").html(data);
    });
}
```

Basically, you could just call `get_page_content('home')` and you would get the view from the action 'home'. You need to have the 'Pages' controller and an action for each page (home, about, contact...). Don't forget the routes.
If you want, you can change it to send the POST request instead of GET.

Comment: Thanks @anis alibegic how I implement the script code like where do I add it

Comment: You can add at the bottom of the page. Then call the function from every navigation link. For example: Home calls `get_page_content('home')`, About calls `get_page_content('about')` and etc.
You need the Pages controller as well as all the actions, for now. 


Something like this: 
`class Pages extends CI_Controller {
 public function home() {
  $this->load->view('pages/home');
 }

 public function about() {
  $this->load->view('pages/about');
 }
}`

Then you need to add the routes to the actions. That's all.